# Drop Down Control Issue in IE9,IE10. Selected Option not displayed in drop down box

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have a drop down control in my web page. That's viewed Collection Dictionary value.
Here i added One Option value in top of the drop down list with enabled selected option using J query.since the newly one added using [j query] was selected in drop down box after page render except the IE9,IE10 browser.

Please find the sample code.

collection code:

```
Dictionary<string,string> PlatformList=new Dictionary<string,string>();
PlatformList.Add("asp","ASP.NET")
PlatformList.Add("aspnetmvc","ASP.NET MVC")
PlatformList.Add("wpf","WPF")
PlatformList.Add("silverlight","Silverlight")
```

Here now binded the collection with drop down.

View.cshtml

```
  @Html.DropDownList("platform", new SelectList(PlatformList, "Key", "Value"))
```

Now i have added new Option in the Drop down with enabled selected option Using Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#platform').prepend("<option  value='all'>All</option>");
        $("#platform").find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected'); 

});
```

After page rendered, The newly added one" All Option in selective stage in drop down'
This is worked in IE7,IE8,Mozilla,Chrome.

But In IE9,IE10 the "All" option not viewed  in U drop down.but it locate the top of the list with selected but it hide status.the viewed option in drop down was next to the 
All option is"

```
<option val="all" selected="selected">All</option>==> not viewed in IE9,IE10
<option val="asp">ASP.NET</option>----> this is viewed in IE9,IE10 in case the above issue.
```

please suggest can this support IE9,IE10. if so means, please update the solution.

Comment: Try using `.prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Hi , This is not working..but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#platform').prepend("<option  value='all'>All</option>");
    $("#platform option:selected").removeAttr('selected');
    $("#platform option:first").attr('selected', 'selected'); 
});
```

Your code is not removing the `selected` attribute from the original default, and multiple options with this attribute may be conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Manually changing the index should work, too:

```
$( "#platform" )[ 0 ].selectedIndex = 0;
```